# Update data from view controller which is in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a static table view in my popover. Now the data has changed and I want to update the content of the table view.

The problem is that in `viewDidLoad` the data is gathered (`NSUserDefaults`), but it is only called once. I can't use `viewWillAppear` because of the navigation controller in the popover. It will be called everytime the user navigates back to the main view, but the results will not be correct then. Only if the user taps the save button on the popover the values should be saved, but temporary data should be deleted/ignored. If I'd get the data from `NSUserDefaults` in `viewWillAppear` it would get the old stored data, which is wrong.

Is there a method which can detect if the view controller is presented in a popover (something like *viewDidLoadInPopover*? Than I could gather my data here. Or how could I update my data in the popover?

**Current approach:**

The main view controller (or *master*) and the child view controller (or *detail*) use some local variables to talk to each other (or to transport the data). On `viewWillDisappear` the data from the detail VC is passed to the master VC. Additionally, I set a boolean that I know that a navigation from the detail VC to the master VC happened. For the other direction: Before the transition from the master VC to the detail VC happens the master VC passes it's data to the detail VC.

The complete synchronization with `NSUserDefaults` is only done in the master VC. On `viewWillAppear` I check for my boolean. If the master view isn't appeared because the user navigated back to it, it must be presented from the popover. This is done with my variable, which is set when data is passed from the detail VC to the master VC. If the master VC was presented by a popover I retrieve my values from `NSUserDefaults` and set up my local variables (which are later used to talk between master and detail VC). Otherwise I invert my boolean variable so that it is only done once. This approach relies on the fact that my custom methods (which will be called from the detail VC to pass the data to the master VC) are called before `viewWillAppear` is called. This is the ugly part for me.
When the user presses the save button on the master VC the local variables are stored back into `NSUserDefaults`.

Through this approach the popover can be called on multiple view controllers and the data in it is always up to date.

Comment: You can implement a delegation relationship. Your main view controller could be a delegate of your popover view controller. Whatever change in your popover is immediately passed to your main view controller through this delegation.

Comment: when ever there is data change you can reload tableview.when ever you are saving data to nsuserdefaults you call the delegate,implement that method of delegate in you popoverclass and reload table view in popover.

Comment: @OnikIV: What do you mean by *whatever change in your popover*? Do you mean my data of my view controller? So I call a method from the delegate and this method passes the data to the main view controller?

Comment: @Jignesh: I'm saving the data and then I dismiss the popover (still in memory?). If I call the method of the delegate the table view will not be visible anymore. Will reloading the table view will make sense here?

Comment: @testin. Yes, You can pass a method(with its var) from a object to its delegate. This is delegation. If you write here a bit about your code with the popover class, your main view class, and what do you want pass. I could write in an answer the protocol (you must create), and a bit about delegation code.

Comment: @OnikIV: My code is in C#. That's the reason why I didn't add it at the beginning. Don't know if it would help you if I add it here. Currently, I'm using another approach, which seems to work but is kind of ugly I think. I'll update my question for this. Don't know if your approach works for my use case. Would I need a reference to the delegate on all places where I change the data?

Comment: @testing I can't help you in C#. Sorry.

Comment: @OnikIV: Nevertheless, thanks for your help. One more question: If you read my updated question would that also work with your delegate & protocol?

Comment: @testing. I don't understand very well about your code. (You have viewWillApper and others methods ?.) Because another easy approach is use the NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification. In objective-C, is adding this line a your viewWillAppear:     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodYouWantFire) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];   And any change in user defaults make the: "methodYouWantFire" will be call. (You can implement this in both).

Comment: Now I tried your tip. It would work. What I see the notification is sent multiple times. I think it's because for each value which changed the notification is sent. Is this right?

Comment: Custom notifications are better for that, though I don't know where I should unsubscribe from the notification center. When the view is in memory it should receive the notifications, but `viewWillDisappear` is not enough (need to know when the popover is in the process of being dismissed). Currently, every load of the view creates the popover which subscribes again to the notification center. Seems that I stay with my old approach.